# Outlook - Forward/Reply remove display:none inline-style

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've created a Mail-Template for a Sharepoint WebPart which includes a div element with inline style display: none. Like this:

```
<div style="display: none"> This Text should NOT be visible</div>
```

If I send the Mail-Template to a mail-address, then all will work correctly, that means, div above is not visible. But if I forward or reply the mail, then Outlook overwrites the inline-style and the div above is visible.

I've already tried to set "display: none **!important**" and "mso-hide: all" but that doesn't work for me.

I hope somebody have an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same thing, and I think the only answer is: There is no reliable solution. Even if someone manages to find a solution that works in all current Outlook versions, it might break with the next one.

I have tried `opacity: 0`, `visibility: hidden`, `mso-hide: all`, `font-size: 0`, etc. None of these work because they are stripped out by Outlook.

Hiding the text using conditional comments results in the text getting deleted when you are forwarding the email.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
Hidden content
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

So, if your goal is to store metadata for email processing, I'd recommend to just add it to the bottom of the email with a smaller text size, and in a human readable format (something like `Reference Nr.: 123456`). This will not get deleted by Outlook and it would also survive a conversion to plain text in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `display:none`, Try to use `font-size:0px` or `height:0px`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. This solution does not working for me. Result: Div was always visible, not only on forward or reply.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. tried display:none !important as inline. but when forwarded, the mail in my inbox become remove the hide style but the recipient will get the div as hidden!

Answer (score 0):

I found one hack to keep the text hidden on reply/fwd from Outlook Desktop is that set text and background color same. So far I am not able to see the text on both